# What is the equivalent of set termout off in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spool

In Oracle SQLPlus, I can write:

```
set termout off
spool data.out
@query.sql
spool off
```

to make sure the query output is sent to the file `data.out` and not to the terminal.  Is there a way I can do the same in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
mysql> tee data.out
mysql> source query.sql
mysql> notee
```

and it will copy the output to the file, but it will also show it on the terminal. I don't think there's a way to disable the terminal output completely.

You could execute the command from the shell instead of the `mysql>` interactive session, and use the shell's output redirection.

```
mysql < query.sql > data.out
```